# Exclude button from disabling

Tags: swift, swiftui, disable

I have custom view with different content inside including Button.

For example:

```
VStack {
   Text("Some text")
   Button() // 1-th
   Button() // 2-th
      .disabled(false) // This doesn't help, despite it logical
}
.disabled(true) // Line with disabling
```

I want 2-th button to be always enabled no matter what is set in "Line with disabling".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid/disabled(_:)) this does not work that way. It works the other way around. As you allready discovered the `.disable` on the parent overrides the value set in the child.

Possible solution would be to not use the parent `.disable` instead use it on each child element.

Answer (score 0):

And what do you think about this:

```swift
VStack {
    Text("Some text")

    Button(action: {
        print("Button Action 1")
    }, label: {
        Text("Button 1")
    })

    Button(action: {
        print("Button Action 1")
    }, label: {
        Text("Button 1")
    })
    .environment(\.isEnabled, true)
}
.disabled(true)
```

Based on [SwiftUI Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/):

You can set or override some values using the environment(*:*:) view modifier:

```
MyView()
    .environment(\.lineLimit, 2)
```

So why couldn't you override `.environment(\.isEnabled, true)` like in example above? It works like a charm, but I have no idea what problems or other shortcomings it could cause when using it.